# How to use ADB in a Batch file to open a Windows File Explorer window

Tags: windows-explorer, batch, batch-file, android, adb

I tried posting this on Stack but was told it may be more appropriate here.

I'm trying to run a bat that will open a folder on an android device using ADB in Windows.

For the life of me I have searched and hacked my way through to nowhere (my search skills are fairly weak, so sorry if this is a dupe).

I can easily do it on a Windows folder with START but that doesn't seem to work within the ADB command structure.

```
adb -s %%G Start "/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.title/files/"
```

Errors out.

Seems adb does not like start, wondering if anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ADB and MTP the protocol used by Windows Explorer are two distinct protocols. You can't mix them up. The Explorer has no path for folders on an MTP devices (there seems to be a way to construct one but this is very complicated see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13452798/150978). And via ADB there is no way to show the files in a graphical way (without third party software).

Comment: Potential duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397348/open-folder-on-portable-device-with-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there may not be a good way to do this. As noted in the comments, there are multiple ways of accessing a device. The relevant ones are [MTP, PTP](https://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/) and something like "USB tethering" (the option used with ADB).

To the best of my knowledge, MTP and PTP are the only protocols that allow Explorer to display typical GUI directory listings. With that in mind, I personally haven't found a good way to call these locations from the command line/batch file.

Alternatively, you could run `adb shell` to get an interactive shell, then run `cd` with some location e.g. `cd /storage/emulated/0`. But in my experience, this A) won't appear in Explorer and B) doesn't seem like it can be easily automated (i.e trying to send keyboard input directly to the interactive shell after running `adb shell`).

---

*Note that you can run indivudual `adb shell` commands with something like e.g. `adb shell ls /storage/emulated/0 > directory_listing.txt` to generate a text list of files/folder names in a given directory. But the `adb shell` isn't interactive in this case, so commands must be issued one at a time (as far as I am aware).*

Answer (score 0):

Following up with the information, (mainly the protocols) you guys provided took me to this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397348/open-folder-on-portable-device-with-batch-file

This works, its not pretty but it works! Now to just find a way to automate the first part and I'm laughing.

Thanks for the point in the right direction.